# Clone an instance in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, automation, google-compute-engine, clone, gcloud

I need a **Compute Engine instance** to import the exact configuration (IP, services, **files**, etc...) of the original machine, without impacting the frontend if it concerns a web server for example. While running this machine, I would be able to shut down the original machine to increase its RAM or vCPUs before starting it again and deleting the cloned instance.

The problem is that I want to automate this process, and that's why I need the gcloud command. So is there a way to **clone** an entire gcp instance using the **gcloud** command or another tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with the gcloud. This is possible with the cloud console, but as you can see in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-vm-from-similar-instance#restrictions):

> Restrictions
>
> You can only use this feature in the Cloud Console; this feature is not supported in the gcloud tool or the API.

What you could do is create similar (not completely equal) instances from a [custom image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#custom_images), using that all you have to do is use the following command:

```
gcloud compute instances create --image=IMAGE
```

More details on that command can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create#--image)